# Importing module gives "name not defined" error even though the variable is defined before the import

Tags: python, nameerror

I have created a very basic script which I saved and can import into Python just fine and I have checked it works, yet I keep coming up with a "name not defined error" even though I have defined the variable before importing it - I have tried global command etc. and nothing.

`Seasons.py`

```
if favorite_season == "Winter":
    print("Let it snow!")
```

```
>>> favorite_season = "Winter"
>>> import Seasons
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Kaz\documents\Seasons.py", line 1, in <module>
    if favorite_season == "Winter":
NameError: name 'favorite_season' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: imported scripts don't have access to variables declared before the import

Answer (score 2):

The imported modules are ran in isolation, without access to externally scoped variables.

If you want to use external variables inside of other modules, best to use functions

`Seasons.py`

```
def check(favorite_season):
  if favorite_seaon == "Winter":
     print("Let it snow!")
```

```
>>> favorite_season = "Winter"
>>> import Seasons
>>> Seasons.check(favorite_season)
Let it snow!
```

Comment: Thank you - so as I said below code is actually best copied and pasted not imported ? Apologies for the daft questions

Comment: Not sure I understand. Nothing is copied/pasted here and I am still using an import

Answer (score 0):

The variable needs to be defined *in the code that is using the variable* (i.e. in your case in the file `Seasons.py`), not in the code that is importing the module inside which the variable is used.

Comment: So there is no way to make the variable selective ? e.g. summer winter fall or spring ? the idea was to have the favorite season as selective and the output would change

Comment: The right name for that is [namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: `The important thing to know about namespaces is that there is absolutely no relation between names in different namespaces; for instance, two different modules may both define a function maximize without confusion` part of documentation I guess

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there are scope for the memory.

Here you define favorite_season in the main interactive scope. When you import your module, it has its own scope and your main interactive scope in the console will be able to access this scope. But the opposite is not true.

In particular, we usually don’t expect an imported module to execute code (or very few in some specific case), just propose new methods and classes that you will be able to use.

Answer (score 0):

Variables belong to the module they are inside of. Unless they are inside of a class or function, then they belong to the class or function they are inside of. Google `python scoping` for more information on how that works. You can do the following:

Inside `main.py`:

```
favorite_season = "Winter"
import Seasons
```

Inside `Seasons.py`:

```
import main

if main.favorite_season == "Winter":
    print("Snuggled Up Warm")
elif main.favorite_season == "Summer":
    print("Yummy Ice Cream")
elif main.favorite_season == "Spring":
    print("Pretty Petals")
else:
    print("Crunchy Bright Leaves")
```

And then on the terminal you can now run

> python3 main.py

Which will correctly output

> Snuggled Up Warm

And that will work. However, it's best to create functions instead as modules will only run once, but functions can be used as many times as you want. That would be done like so:

Inside `main.py`:

```
import Seasons
Seasons.print_seasonal_message("Winter")
```

Inside `Seasons.py`:

```
def print_seasonal_message(season)
    if season == "Winter":
        print("Snuggled Up Warm")
    elif season == "Summer":
        print("Yummy Ice Cream")
    elif season == "Spring":
        print("Pretty Petals")
    else:
        print("Crunchy Bright Leaves")
```

Comment: Thank you appreciate it - so as I understand it from yourself and @oneCricketeer code like that is actually better copied and pasted rather than imported ?

Comment: You can still import functions. Nothing should need to be copied and pasted. I've edited my answer to show you how this would be done using an imported function.